# enable embedded youtube videos "allowfullscreen" through CSS

Tags: javascript, css, opencart, opencart2.3

I am using opencart 2.3 (opensource CMS, it is an eCommerce)

I have embeded youtube videos, but after adding multiple products, I noticed that "full screen" is not enabled.

From what I read, all I need to do is add the attribute "allowfullscreen" in the HTML code to something like this

```
<iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/n_drgwergwwe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Now I found the javascript code that generates the attributes and I can add the "allowfullscreen" attribute to be generated as well for future products I add, but what do I do about all the products already created without said attribute?

Can I add this attribute through the use of CSS? I am able to change the iframe width, height, but what about the "allowfullscreen" attribute?

Anything would be helpful really.
Thanks :)

Comment: No you can't, it's an HTML attribute and has nothing to do with CSS. You have to use javascript to add it if you can't modify the HTML.

Comment: Okay, well, I guess that settles it. Thanks :)

Comment: @MichaelCoker you might want to write it as an answer, so that it is marked as answered, because i almost overlooked the question, beeing without answer, while I was having the same problem.